# Какой паттерн можно применить для взаимодействия экземпляров с элементами DOM?

Tags: javascript, ооп, dom

Изучаю джаваскрипт. Пробую применять ооп, но не всё получается.
Стараюсь разбираться **без сторонних библиотек**, только встроенными инструментами. 
Сейчас не знаю как удобно наладить взаимодействие с DOM.

Создал я например объект "мячик".
Объект мячик - это экземпляр класса.
У него есть методы: "катится", "прыгает".
Но у него так же должно быть представление в виде элемента DOM, которое является его частью и отображает его на экране.

Как удобно выстроить такое взаимодействие с его элементом?

У меня пока есть только идея адаптировать (паттерн адаптер) тег - который представляет из себя мячик и расширять его необходимыми свойствами:

```
// код не проверял

function Мячик(тегТипаМячик){
    this.тег = тегТипаМячик
}
Мячик.prototype.катится = function(){
    // просто лёгкий пример
    var следующаяПозиция = this.тег.parentElement.nextElementSibling
    this.удаляетсяСЭкрана()
    следующаяПозиция.appendChild(this.тег)
}
Мячик.prototype.удаляетсяСЭкрана = function(){
    this.тег.parentElement.removeChild(this.тег)
}

var мячик = new Мячик(document.getElementById("мячик")
мячик.катится()
```

Но на практике, учитывая наследование и другие взаимодействующие объекты, получается путаный и не очень удобный код. Может, конечно, это мне ещё синтаксис языка непривычен...

Подумал, что наверняка для таких решений есть уже отработанные шаблоны. Вот подскажите как обычно вы такую задачу решаете. Какой шаблон будет наиболее удобным и подходящим?

Спасибо.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52284/discussion-on-question-by--------).

Answer (score 4):

То, что вам нужно, обычно называют термином "компонент". Еще иногда говорят "контрол" (это слово пришло из десктопных приложений). Именно эти слова следует использовать для поиска в интернете.

Собственно, именно так паттерн обычно и называется. Только вот ничего толкового вы про него не найдете - потому что у каждой библиотеки свое понимание этого паттерна, общего определения не существует...

Из общеизвестных паттернов имеет смысл вспомнить паттерн [Composite](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29).

---

Вам подойдет любая из библиотек, которые реализуют компоненты. Их полно:

1. [Angular](https://angular.io/) (также известная как Angular 2, не путать первой версией, известной как AngularJs) - построена вокруг идеи компонентов.
2. [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/) - в последних версиях также появились компоненты. Довольно хорошо подходит для задачи "оживления" готовой верстки.
3. [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) - не совсем то, что вам нужно (эта библиотека отвечает только за представление, а вам нужны компоненты с полным поведением) - но компоненты тут есть.
4. [Preact](https://preactjs.com/) - почти как React, но по-другому, и компоненты тут тоже есть.
5. [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/feature-overview) - библиотека, использующая [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Web_Components). И содержащая полифилы для старых браузеров к ним же.
6. [JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) - вообще-то это библиотека с кучей готовых компонентов - но тут есть и механизмы для создания новых.

Список неполный, в нем только те библиотеки про которые лично я достаточно часто слышал. Гуглите и найдете больше :)

---

Если же вам нужен свой велосипед, могу рекоментовать следующее.

**Во-первых**, забудьте про Web Components - браузеры их до сих пор не реализуют полностью, а значит, вам понадобятся полифилы. А полифилы к Web Components - это Polymer, а не велосипед :)

**Во-вторых**, сделайте свойство `тэг` приватным, чтобы к нему имел доступ только сам компонент! В понимании javascript, приватное свойство - это свойство, которое начинается с подчеркивания. (Я не шучу! Надо просто принять за правило никогда не лезть в чужие свойства, которые начинаются с подчеркивания. Некоторые IDE об этом даже знают и не дают контекстных подсказок по поводу таких свойств).

Отсюда следует **в-третьих** - каждому компоненту надо выделить свой собственный тэг, не допускайте чтобы два компонента "сидели" на одном тэге.

А отсюда следует **в-четвертых** - сведите к минимуму прямое взаимодействие с деревом DOM, чтобы случайно не нарушить работу дочерних или родительских компонентов. Возможно, вам понадобится отдельное дерево компонентов, отличное от дерева элементов DOM.

Возвращаясь к примеру с вашим мячиком: у вас мячик сам выбирает куда ему "перекатываться". Это будет работать пока ваш мячик один на странице. И даже когда вы его разместите в компоненте, который "знает" про всех своих детей. Но если вдруг вы сделаете общий компонент вроде "таблицы" или "списка", способный вмещать произвольные элементы - и попытаетесь положить внутрь мячик - то может *внезапно* оказаться, что представления мячика о структуре родителя с реальностью не совпадают.

Старайтесь избегать ситуаций, когда компонент сам решает где ему разместиться на странице. В данном случае в компонент стоило бы вынести не мячик - а то поле, по которому он катится.

**В-пятых**, разберитесь с обработкой событий. Возможно, проще всего будет свой велосипед - в интернете полно примеров реализаций. А может быть, лучше будет разобраться с [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

**В-шестых**, вам придется придумать что-нибудь для CSS, чтобы вложенные компоненты не "мешали" друг другу. Возможно, вам понравится [БЭМ](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/) (это шутка, он никому не нравится (это снова шутка, кому-то он все же нравится, иначе бы им не пользовались)). Подробное сравнение CSS-методологий можно увидеть тут: https://habrahabr.ru/post/256109/

Comment: А это только у меня вначале вопроса жирными буквами написано что без сторонних библиотек?

Comment: @OlmerDale Сторонние библиотеки можно не только применять, но и читать в поисках вдохновения.

Comment: Вот если бы у автора было написано function Кнопка(){}, то я бы с Вами согласился. Но Вам не кажется странным что написано мячик? Вы когда-нибудь видели в разговорах о компонентах примеры с мячами или котятами?

Comment: @OlmerDale э... простите, но какое отношение это имеет к моему ответу?

Comment: Просто у меня не вяжутся ангуляр и мячи.. Но это ладно. Вот скажите, когда Вы только начали изучать js, Вы прям сразу начали изучать исходники самых сложных фраймворков? Лично мне кажется что человек который только начал изучать js перехочит это делать открыв исходники angular. И мне нет никакого-дела, просто есть немного свободного времени и я не могу удержаться и не сказать что этот ответ может быть полезен всем кроме автора.

Comment: @OlmerDale, напишите свой очешуительный ответ с мячиками и котятами, делов то

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму человек только начавший изучать js попросил объяснить ему принцип без использования библиотек! И что он получил? Список фраймворков для изучения в то время, когда даже ещё основы языка не известны. Просто, как Вы сказали очешуительно!

Comment: @OlmerDale, я вижу в ответе не только список фреймворков для изучения, а ряд полезных советов еще. Так что такой ответ гораздо лучше молчания. А классного ответа для начинающих с мячиками и котятами до сих пор никто не пишет почему-то. Я не пишу потому что мне слабо, а Вы то что?

Comment: Короче, я вспомнил компоновщик. Он нужен чтобы древовидные структуры формировать, обходить их и перебирать было удобно, вроде менюшек вложенных друг в друга и т.д, возможно и DOM с его помощью построен, потому что это тоже древовидная структура. Но я не вижу как его применить для решения задачи, которую я спрашивал.

Comment: @МистерФикс когда вы начнете всерьез работать с визуальными компонентами - быстро окажется, что у одного компонента могут быть дочерние компоненты, про которые он к тому же мало что знает. Тут-то паттерн "компоновщик" и понадобится.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, тут вы правы.